# Как получить данные после get-запроса через определённый промежуток времени?

Tags: javascript, ajax, get

У меня есть ссылка. По ссылке находится страница с ajax содержимым. Оно подгружается через несколько секунд после открытия. Мне нужно получить тот html, который получится после полной загрузки.

Если использовать метод get,

```
$.get(link, function(data){
})
```

то data внутри метода будет содержать html до подгрузки ajax-контента. И внутри нужного элемента будет, например, текст "Loading..." вместо нужной информации.

Нужен способ получить data после того, как загрузится весь контент. Не обязательно это как-то отслеживать, можно просто через какой-то промежуток времени (несколько секунд). Что-то наподобие:

```
$.get(link, function(
      setInterval(data, 3000)){
})
```

Comment: можете пояснить зачем вы так делаете? какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: Находясь на одной странице (результаты поиска), мне надо получить информацию с другой страницы (профиль из результатов). Не переходя по ссылке, только джаваскриптом.

Comment: а профиль вы запрашиваете с сервера?

Comment: профиль я хочу получить просто html-страницей, методом get. С обычными сайтами, без ajax, такой способ работает. Get возвращает полную структуру и по ней можно искать обычным document.querySelector. А вот с ajax-контентом сталкиваюсь впервые.

Comment: такое можно сделать используя скрытый iframe. но это не очень хороший вариант. вы не правильно понимает принцип работы xhr. через xhr вы получаете html, но браузер его не обрабатывает,  т.е. js на нем не выполняется.

Comment: Хорошо, ясно. Если так получить данные нельзя, может есть другие подходящие способы (у сервиса нет api)?

Comment: как сервис формирует страницу с профилем?

Comment: В исходнике обычный html. В тегах, где должна быть информация, изначально находятся слова "loading". После открытия страницы запускается js и заполняет эти теги информацией.

Comment: вот и изучите какие запросы делает эта страница.